# Get data from external website in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have to develop an app using phonegap (HTML5, css, javascript, json, jquery,...).
This app should have to open an external website (using inAppBrowser) to login and then go back to the app providing a token.
Now I can open the external website but I don't know how to go back to the app.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Omar

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote some code roughly to retrieve data from external website. Hope this helps:

```
var yourApp = {
getData : function(q) {

var search_url = "http://xyz.com/xyz/customfeed?filterby=custom&urlfilter=1&" + q;
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: search_url,
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(xml) {
    $('entry', xml).each(function() {

      var hi = new xyzDataItem();
      hi.title = $(this).find('title:eq(0)').text();
      hi.link = $(this).find('link:eq(0)').attr('href');
      hi.desc = $(this).find('summary:eq(0)').text();
      hi.date = $(this).find('updated:eq(0)').text();
      hi.id = $(this).find('id:eq(0)').text();
      $("#loading").hide();
          $("#search_results").append('<div class="abc">' +
          '<h2>' + hi.title + '</h2>' +
          '<P>' + hi.desc + '</p>' +
          '<P><a href="' + hi.link + '" class="external">xyzData</a></p>' +
          '</div>');
        });
    }
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InAppBrowser then do the following:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
          if (event.url,indexOf("http://apache.org") > -1){
              //do something
          } 

     });
}
```

Ideally the token should be part of the URL so that it is easier to retrieve. Else use $.getJSON method and do not use InAppBrowser. But if using InAppBrowser then the token should be a query string parameter.

E.g. http://yoursite.com/loginsuccess?token=adsfsadfdsfasdf